# How to stop unnecessary re-render of the custom hook and Student component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the below code snippet, `useStudentState` custom hook and `Student` component are being rendered even if only the first `<Student {...studentStateA} />` component is changed.

For e.g., If you enter a new value in the first input box and press `Enter`. The custom hook `useStudentState` and `Student` component are rendered twice, once for each child.

I want `Student` to be a dumb component. Is there something wrong with the architecture and how can I avoid this unnecessary rerendering of other children (`<Student {...studentStateB} />`) and custom hook in the `App` component?

The code looks like this:

```
// App.jsx

import Student from "./Student";
import useStudentState from "./useStudentState";

const initialStudentsA = ["foo", "bar"];
const initialStudentsB = ["bat", "baz"];

function App() {
  const studentStateA = useStudentState({ initialStudents: initialStudentsA });
  const studentStateB = useStudentState({ initialStudents: initialStudentsB });

  return (
    <>
      <Student {...studentStateA} />
      <Student {...studentStateB} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


//Student.jsx
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Student({ addStudent, students } = {}) {
  console.log("Student component rendered!");
  const [newLabel, setNewLabel] = useState("");

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setNewLabel(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    addStudent?.(newLabel);
    setNewLabel("");
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={newLabel}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          placeholder="Add a student"
        />
      </form>

      {students &&
        students.length > 0 &&
        students.map((name, i) => <span key={i}>{name}, &nbsp;</span>)}
    </>
  );
}


//useStudentState.jsx
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useStudentState({ initialStudents } = {}) {
  console.log('custom hook');
  const [students, setStudents] = useState(initialStudents || []);

  const addStudent = name => {
    setStudents([...students, name]);
  };

  return {
    addStudent,
    students,
  };
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-forest-9tqht7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, create a wrapper class called `StudentWrapper` that contains the `useStudentState` custom hook and returns a `Student` component:

```
import Student from "./Student";
import useStudentState from "./useStudentState";

function StudentWrapper({ initialStudents }) {
   const { addStudent, students } = useStudentState({ initialStudents });
   return <Student addStudent={addStudent} students={students} />;
}

export default StudentWrapper;
```

Your `App` component then renders as many `StudentWrapper` components as you want.

```
import StudentWrapper from "./StudentWrapper";

const initialStudentsA = ["foo", "bar"];
const initialStudentsB = ["bat", "baz"];

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <StudentWrapper initialStudents={initialStudentsA} />
      <StudentWrapper initialStudents={initialStudentsB} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

By having only one hook per component *(unlike what you had on `App` component)* and by seperating its logic from the input changeable state, you can avoid this unnecessary re-render.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-monad-7jk5zd

Comment: This works fine. Thank you :) But why having two instances of a custom hook in a component is a problem? Don't they have their own scope and are independent?

Comment: @newbie Having two instances of a hook in a single component is fine depending on the context, but by putting all the state in `<App>` you make it so that changes in one component cause `<App>` (and therefore its children) to rerender, which may be (and in this case is) unnecessary.